# Mongodb Count and where

Tags: mongodb, count, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to count how many times a particular user viewed some  record. What will be the query for it ?

I have collection which logs user activity. Every time a user views something a row is created in that collection. So I want to count how many times a user does some  thing

I am trying this but not working

```
db.activities.aggregate(
    {$group: { 
        _id: "$assetName", 
        count: { $sum: 1}
        }},
        {$match: {
            "userId": "1"
        }}
);
```

**Example**

```
User A viewed Company ABC
User A viewed Company XYZ
```

again

```
User A viewed Company ABC
User B viewed company TEST
```

**Expected result**

```
1. Company A viewed 2 times by user 1
2. Company B viewed 5 times by user 1
```

Comment: try this: Model.find({"company":"A","userId":"1"}).count(function(err, count){});

Comment: not a specific company, all the companies that user viewed, I need its sum/count

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.activities.aggregate({$group: {_id: {comp: "$assetName",
                                       rec_id: "$recordId",
                                       user: "$userId"}, 
                                 count: {$sum: 1}}})
```

Comment: and If I want to sort that record in desc order then?

Comment: modified my answer. check that.

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day. Last question please

the assetName in query is actually company name
I have recordId field in the collection i also want to include it then the query will be?

Comment: How to translate this query into mongoose.js ?

Comment: i don't know mongoose. sorry. Is record id common for all assets?

Comment: what is this comp??

Comment: recordId is different for different companies
Suppose A comapny has Id 1
B company has Id 2

Comment: but company A in all records will have same record id as "1". correct?

Comment: for translate to mongoose you need to do just: Model.aggregate

Comment: yes I searched on internet and find it how to translate thank you

Comment: in that case you can add record id as like company name

Comment: How to add the record field please assist me